# Detect the first user interaction (touches, press, tap, pan, pinch, etc.) after app starts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

Is there a way to detect the first user interaction right after app starts?

I have an app that on the main view it has a navigation bar with 5 buttons, a top half with scroll view and a bottom half with another scroll view.  When app starts, I have an animation of a series of images going on the top half.  And as soon as user touch, press, tap any buttons, or any where, I need the animation to stop.

I can make the buttons, top half scroll view and bottom half scroll view to post a notification so my observer can handle the stopping of the animation.  But I just thought there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are touch delegate methods, such as `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, `(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches</span> withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, and `(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. Put these in the view controller of whatever screen appears first. And you can handle touch events. Note you will have to set objects, or views to `[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` or something like that in order to receive touch events.

Comment: Well, that was my original approach.  But it did seem to work as well as the solution I posted in my question. Good try!